# TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I try to pass Id from a component to another component. To do that I used

```
<a className="btn btn-view" href={`/buyer/viewpostdetails/${posts._id}`}>View Post <i className="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
```

this code. It works correctly and shows the URL correctly with the ID.

Then I tried to get that Id

```
    componentDidMount(){
            const id = this.props.match.params.id;

            axios.get(`/post/${id}`).then((res) => {
                if (res.data.success) {
                    this.setState({
                        post:res.data.post
                    });
                    console.log(this.state.post);
                }
            });
    }
```

I used the above code to do that but I got an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Is that a simple link? What do you think `this.props.match.params.id` is? Are you using `react-router`?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros this is the URL that I got "http://localhost:3000/buyer/viewpostdetails/60f7d7fbd89c5a1470919a24". I want to get this id into the above id variable. That's why I used this "this.props.match.params.id".

Comment: Can you show the rest of the relevant code?

Comment: @yochanansheinberger this is the code that I used to do this                                           `constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            post:{}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const id = this.props.match.params.id;

        axios.get(`/post/${id}`).then((res) => {
            if (res.data.success) {
                this.setState({
                    post:res.data.post
                });
                console.log(this.state.post);
            }
        });
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
// import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={FirstPage} exact />
          <Route path="/:id" component={SecondPage} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
function FirstPage() {
  const [post, setPost] = useState({ _id: 5 });
  return (
    <div>
      <div>First Page</div>
      <Link to={`/${post._id}`}>Link</Link>
    </div>
  );
}

function SecondPage(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = props.match.params.id;
    setState(id);
    // axios.get(`/post/${id}`).then((res) => {
    //   if (res.data.success) {
    //     setState(res.data.post);
    //   }
    // });
  }, []);
  return <div>SecondPage id: {state}</div>;
}
```

You must do something like that.
First you define a router.
Then you can access the id from the relevant page or component.
And I suggest you to define components as functions and use useEffect and useState hooks.

Comment: Thanks so much, @ibrahimAKIN. I appreciate your help!